# Interpreting a plot about heteroskedasticity

Tags: heteroscedasticity

Can anyone tell me whether this graph shows heteroscedasticity? 
If the graph shows heteroscedasticity, how can I  solve it?

[image: rvfplot]

Comment: It does look like there is an increase in variance with bigger fitted values, try a test for heteroskedasticity such as `ncvTest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

This does seem to show some heteroskedasticity. It also shows three points that have large negative residuals (the cluster on the lower right) - I would investigate those.

I would also modify the plot. There is a lot of data and the size and solidity of the plotting symbol makes it hard to see what is going on.  I'd either use a much smaller symbol or a somewhat transparent one. I'd also add a loess curve.

As to how to "solve" it, first try to figure out what is going on.

There are two sorts of solutions to problems like this. One is to transform one or more variables, the other is to use a method that does not rely on homoskedasticity.  You don't say what the variables in your model are, so it's hard to give detailed advice.  In general, I favor using other methods unless there is a substantive reason to transform the variables.

You might try quantile regression (I recently wrote a[n introduction to quantile regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-quantile-regression-eca5e3e2036a) ), regression trees, robust regression or possibly something else, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It really helped, i'm going to use robust regression. Thanks very much.